# jquery valid email check

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Validate email address in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

I am just a beginner in jquery.I have used email field in my form. The form shouldn't submit if the email field is empty. I used the following code

```
if(document.getElementById('emailaddress').value == ''){
alert('Enter the Email Address');
document.getElementById('emailaddress').focus();
return false;
}
```

How can i check the entered email is a valid one using simple jquery?

Comment: Do you want to verify that the value entered is a properly-formatted email address, or just that there is some text entered?

Comment: I want to check the value entered is a properly-formatted email address.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use the [jquery validate plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).

A live email validation demo can be seen [here](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/)

Here is some sample code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
   $("#myForm").validate({
    rules: {
      emailaddress : {
        required: true,
        email: true
      }
    }
   });
});
</script>
<form id="myForm">
Email address: <input type="text" name="emailaddress" id="emailaddress" class="required" >
</form>
```